# Show with three characters like Power Rangers

Tags: story-identification, tv

I don't know the name of the show, but the cast was Korean, Chinese, or Japanese. There were two boys and one girl. The three of them were like Power Rangers, but it is not a *Power Rangers* show. There were red, black and sky blue rangers. The show is from maybe the period of 2000 through 2010.

Comment: [Beetleborgs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bad_Beetleborgs)? [VR Troopers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VR_Troopers)?

Answer (score 14):

I believe this is [Justirisers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genseishin_Justirisers). It is a Japanese [tokusatsu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokusatsu) TV series that ran from 2004 to 2005. Notably, it featured only three heroes, in exactly the colors you describe. Here's what they look like:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another *possibility* may be  **VR Troopers.** The years are a bit off [1995-97] but it has the same tokasatsu feel, a girl and 2 guys fighting. It was even made by Saban, the company responsible for Power Rangers. Here's what they look like:

[image]